# Why did the LOTR and Hobbit films use the "Wilhelm Scream" so much?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-lord-of-the-rings, movie, the-hobbit, wilhelm-scream

I was wondering if there was a reason the director (or people who choose sound effects) littered the LOTR and *Hobbit* films with so many "Wilhelm Screams"?

It really ruined the movies for me, to a point that every time I hear one I feel like turning it off!

**Was there any information as to why the sound director used it so much?**

This is not a rant question, but more so why it was used so much. I was really interested to know the reason for its use.

---

For reference, here is a compilation and it is not small:

Comment: 6 times in over 24 hours worth of films is hardly over-user

Comment: @Valorum, well, used one time is overuse. Glad you like the Wilhelm Scream, I don't.

Comment: A few of those seemed very fake

Answer (score 12):

According to Steve Lee (sound designer, film historian and Wilhelm Scream expert) Peter Jackson's love affair with the Wilhelm Scream came about during the sound-editing of LOTR: The Two Towers when his sound team explained the [long and storied history](https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=384&v=_PxALy22utc) of this particular sound effect.

Like many directors before him, he apparently vowed to include it in all of his future films, where circumstances allow.

> *When Peter Jackson was told the history of the Wilhelm during the
> sound mix of "The Lord of the Rings: The Two Towers" (2002), he was so
> excited it was included that he had its volume raised - and insisted
> that it also be used in "Return of the King" (2003).*
>
> <sub><sup>[Hollywood Lost and Found: The WILHELM Scream](http://hollywoodlostandfound.net/wilhelm/)</sup></sub>

Comment: And yet you think it has not been overused. Increasing the volume to make it more pronounced is certainly a sing that it is not just normal use.

Comment: @KyloRen - When I hear it in films, I always raise a mental glass to the Director. When *done well* it's a connection to a century of Hollywood history and a sign that the makers genuinely care about making a quality product.

Comment: At the expense of ruining the movie. Shame really

Comment: @KyloRen - If you feel that a background sound-effect that lasts less than two seconds can ruin a 240 minute film, then I can't really help you.

Comment: It is unfortunate, but it really does ruin the movie for me.

Comment: @KyloRen - It may interest you to learn that it's one of a range of stock sounds that are recycled around Hollywood. "Dirty Harry's gun" has been used in nearly 300 films and the "Bwooo" sound features in more than 50 trailers; https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=38&v=yP3uXtFozv0

Comment: I know about that sound, but it is far less obvious.

Comment: Ugh that "BWOOoo" sound is far more annoying than the Wilhelm Scream.

Comment: @KyloRen You say this question is not a rant, but your many comments would indicate otherwise.

Comment: @DJClayworth, if you think so, then down vote. I don't care what anyone else thinks.

Answer (score 3):

I find it has a dual purpose of a nod to Hollywood history, and to elicit a smile and a chuckle (to those in the know) without breaking narrative during otherwise sombre and tense moments. Anyone complaining about it is really just bragging about recognizing it.